# Does the electron in a neutral hydrogen atom ever exist in the p, d or f sublevels?

Tags: atoms

I learned that the electron in a neutral hydrogen atom can be excited to higher levels. But there are different sublevels in the levels. For example s, p, d and f.

Does the electron only jump from s sublevel to s sublevel or can it jump to a p sublevel ?

I also learned that an electron always fills the sublevels in order. Does this mean that an electron in a neutral hydrogen atom can only exists in s sublevels ?

Comment: An electron in H always sits in 1s, unless excited. When excited, it can go anywhere.

Comment: Can it go to $2p_y$ ?

Comment: $2p_y$ is not really a state.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Does carbon not have one electron in the $2p_y$ orbital ?

Comment: Orbitals are not quite the same as states.

Comment: You should read up about selection rules which govern what spectroscopic transitions are allowed and which not. As a rule of thumb, s-p, p-d, d-f are allowed but not s-s, p-p, s-d etc.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Can a hydrogen atom that has only one electron have it's electron in the $2p_x$ orbital ?

Comment: An excited hydrogen atom can have an electron in the state with $n=2,\;l=1,\;m=1$. That would be $2p$. But you can't tell whether it is $2p_x$, $2p_y$, or $2p_z$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Great , that answers my question.